# How do I write a bash script to report machine states and conditionally ping them?

Tags: bash

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
array1=(
HPUX2
HPUX3
)

array2=(
`cat $HOME/testo |awk '{print $2}'`
)
```

The file testo,report

```
HPUX2   OFF
HPUX3   ON
```

I want my script to report "Machine HPUX2 is OFF" and
machine HPUX3 is ON, if a machine is ON then the script should `ping` that machine.

Does someone know how to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do :

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
    ping -c1 "$i" &>/dev/null && echo "$i ON" || echo "$i OFF"
done
```